# Change SQL query IS NULL to Laravel Query Builder/Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel

how to change SQL Query

```
SELECT * FROM aps WHERE kategori IS NULL
```

to Laravel Eloquent/Query Builder?

Comment: Just check the Laravel documentation for this.

Comment: ok thanks i got an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `whereNull` function

```
$data=DB::table('aps')->whereNull('kategori')->get();
```

Refer this documentation for further reference https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries

Answer (score 2):

There is the function [`whereNull`](https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_whereNull), so you can just do the following:

```
\DB::table('aps')->whereNull('kategori')->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

If `Ap` is a model, then

```
    $data = Ap::whereNull('kategori')->get();
```

If `aps` is table name, then

```
    $data = DB::table('aps')->whereNull('kategori')->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 $apps = DB::table('aps')
                ->whereNull('kategori');
```

Answer (score 2):

The above query can be written as

```
DB::table('aps')->whereNull('kategori')->get();
```